# Executing curl through Ruby script

Tags: ruby, curl, ssl-certificate, net-http

I'm trying to execute curl through Ruby script using two different methods and have some errors in both.

First method is using shell command

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

`curl --cacert RepoCert --location --request POST 'https://test-service/rest/services/request/' --header 'Authorization: Basic amkkdksmmkk3XCf45DffSa23Ert' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary "{ \"serviceID\": \"3\", \"TypeId\": \"52\", \"requestFieldValues\": { \"summary\": \"summary\", \"description\": \"something\", \"prority\": { \"id\": \"1\"}, \"customfield\": \"5\" }} "`
```

and I have an error

```
"Unexpected character (\u0027s\u0027 (code 115)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: com.itlab.jira.plugins.extender.helper.RequestWrapper$5db70c75; line:1, column:5]"
```

Also tried using Ruby Net::HTTP (code generated from https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/)

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://test-service/rest/services/request/")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Authorization"] = "Basic amkkdksmmkk3XCf45DffSa23Ert"
request.body = JSON.dump({
  "serviceID" => "3",
  "TypeId" => "52",
  "requestFieldValues" => {
    "summary" => "summary",
    "description" => "something",
    "prority" => {
      "id" => "1"
    },
    "customfield" => "5"
  }
})

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

and I get

```
/usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:921:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

The problem is I have to use certificate authorization in this case so I can't ignore it.

Curl executed form command line is working fine. Any idea how to fix one of those methods (or both)?

Comment: First I'd switch from backticks to [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) or the multi-argument form of [`Kernel#system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system). Those will bypass the shell and unwrap one layer of quoting/escaping. Then you can simple things like `system('curl', '--cacert', 'RepoCert', ..., '--data-binary', ruby_hash.to_json)` and stop worrying about who is interpreting which quotes and backslashes.

Comment: `system('curl', ...)` is a really brutal way of doing this, you lose a lot of control. Using Net::HTTP is a step up, if a bit more tricky. I'd recommend [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) which is both powerful and fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for trying to help but I figure it out using Net::HTTP. I leave comment here if someone ever looked for a similar case.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://test-service/rest/services/request/")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.ca_file = "/directory/to/cert/file"

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)

request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Authorization"] = "Basic amkkdksmmkk3XCf45DffSa23Ert"
request.body = JSON.dump({
  "serviceID" => "3",
  "TypeId" => "52",
  "requestFieldValues" => {
    "summary" => "summary",
    "description" => "something",
    "prority" => {
      "id" => "1"
    },
    "customfield" => "5"
  }
})


response = http.request(request)
```